# Struts2 / jQuery: resume link href redirect after e.preventDefault();

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, preventdefault

On my Struts2 application, I have some buttons that will delete items from a table. So far, so good. Now, I'm trying to use jQuery to present the users with an alert to confirm if they really want to delete the chosen item. To do this, what I have in mind is what I think it is the most obvious approach:

> 1. User clicks on the "delete" button;
> 2. Show alert to the user (it contains two links: one to cancel the delete action and another one to confirm it);
>
> > 2.1. If the user presses "cancel", the alert simply goes away;
> >
> > 2.2. If the user presses "confirm", the item is deleted, and then the alert goes away;

What I've got so far:

**JSP:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        [...]
        <td><a href="<s:url action="deleteexperiment"><s:param name="id"><s:property value="exp_id"/></s:param></s:url>" class="delete ink-button all-100">delete</a></td>
        [...]
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="confirm-delete" class="ink-alert basic" role="alert" style="display: none">
    <p class="quarter-bottom-padding"><b>Confirm delete:</b> Do you really want to delete this experiment?</p>
    <button id="no" class="ink-button all-20 red">Cancel</button>
    <button id="yes" class="ink-button all-20 green">Confirm</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.delete').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#confirm-delete').show();

            $('#yes').click(function(event)
            {
                // resume e.preventDefault(), i.e., continue redirecting to the original href on the table above
                $('#confirm-delete').hide();
            });

            $('#no').click(function(event)
            {
                $('#confirm-delete').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried like 20 different approaches (in what concerns trying to restore the original behaviour to the link - the commented line) with no luck. Please note that the `href` atrribute contains Struts tags, so something like `window.location.href = "<s:url action="deleteexperiment"><s:param name="id"><s:property value="exp_id"/></s:param></s:url>";` won't work, because jQuery won't "know" what is the ID, I guess (it will redirect to `http://localhost:8080/AppName/deleteexperiment.action?id=` , so the ID is empty). Unless it would be possible to pass the ID to jQuery when calling the `click()` function, of course. Is that possible? Which other options are left for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.delete').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // store the href attr
        $('#confirm-delete').show();

        $('#yes').click(function(event)
        {
            // resume e.preventDefault(), i.e., continue redirecting to the original href on the table above
            window.location.href = href; // redirect with stored href

            $('#confirm-delete').hide();
        });

        $('#no').click(function(event)
        {
            $('#confirm-delete').hide();
        });
    });
});
```